# Tell if hardwood floor is oiled or laquered

Tags: hardwood-floor, maintenance

From what I understand on the internet, there are two main types of finishing for hardwood floor, oiling and lacquering / painting, and the two kinds require different maintenance.

I have a bedroom with hardwood floor, but I do not have the option of asking the previous owner what of the two options they went for. Is there a good way to tell the two kinds of finishing apart? From what I understand painted floors  can have very varied looks (matte or glossy), so that is not an option.

I have access to a few extra tiles, if that may help, but not to a box of tiles.

EDIT: I added a few pictures, as requested in the comments, trying to focus on damaged areas in the hope that it is more helpful.

[image]
[image]
[image: la]

Comment: What kind of tiles are these? What does the finish look like? Would you post a picture or two? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: @DanielGriscom Added them; sorry! I did not add them in the first place because I thought that a general question on how to tell the two types apart would have been preferred here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oil has no body so the wood grain is just a tiny layer of oil away if you pick an area out of view when you scratch oil it actually will damage the wood,

Lacquering or varnishes like varithane have body and a layer above the wood that can look like a magnifying glass to the grain and when scratched it usually turns color yellow / white this is the layer of “paint” to use your words. You may get a better idea by looking at photos online of oil finished verse varathane most times once you know it is easy to see.